# Overwrite value of the Database, independent of the

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, relational-database, ebean, optimistic-concurrency

Context: Ebean, play-Framework, Model, Optemistic Locking

Is it possible to set an annotation to a value of a model, which tells ebean that it shouldn't throw a "optemistic locking exception" for this value, because it is independent of the previous data?

Example usage: I have a lastAction value, which is updated frequently. It doesn't matter if this value is absolut correct, because it is just used to determin the automated logout time or deletion time (registered and guest user).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can achieve this by using 2 separate tables one for optimistic-lockable attributes, another one for do-not-care attributes.

Later you can combine them in one DB view.

For example:

```
  create table optimistic_lockable {
    id bigint primary key
    ....
  }

  create table non_lockable {
     id primary key
     ,lockable_id foreign key refences optimistic_lockable (id)
  }  

  create view model_view as 
  select * from optimistic_lockable ol, non_lockable nl 
  where ol.id = nl.lockable_id
```

You map your model to `model_view`. And **IFF** the DB engine allows to insert into view, you'll probably be fine ;)

Comment: Thx. Can you give me a short example? I do not know how to split up a model into two tables.

Comment: what DB engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using for development jdbc with the H2 in memory database.

Comment: I'm thinking about, just to create a SqlQuery with Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql) and just to update this value. Would that be overlooked by the optemistic locking.